# Возможно ли в yii2 настроить ЧПУ с GET параметрами в виде массива?

Tags: yii2

Есть контроллер с методом category/view
и есть get параметры:

```
$_GET = [
  'product_id' => 15,
  'brands_id' => [1,2],
  'colors_id' => [1,2]
];
```

Обычные параметры, без массива понятно как настроить, а вот где есть массивы, не очень.

Нужно чтобы получилось что-то вроде
**site.ru/product-15-brand-1-brand-2-color-1-color-2**
или еще как-то, чтобы ссылка была цельная, без ? и &

Возможно ли такое сделать?

Comment: без "?" это уже не GET

Comment: не знаю как в остальных фреймворках, но в yii можно и без ? настроить

Comment: маршрутизация !== GET запрос

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, это будет выглядеть так.

```
[
  [
    'pattern' => 'posts/<product:\d+>/<brand>',
    'route' => 'post/index',
    'defaults' => ['product' => 1, 'brand' => ''],
  ],
]
```

/index.php/posts/15/brandName

[Документация Yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-routing#parameterizing-routes)